# Best way to json encode an array that has a json encoded value already? PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an array with multiple items in it one of which is  an already encoded json string. I'm wanting to json encode the whole array but in doing so it re-json_encodes the json and adds slashes to it. The only way I've found to fix this is to json_decode the value and then encode the whole array. I feel like this is a waste of resources though and I feel like there has to be a better way. Is doing it that way the best possible way?

Here's a sample of the array I'm trying to json_encode.

```
$arr = array();
$arr["var1"] = '{"test":"test"}';
$arr["var2"] = 'foo';
$arr["var3"] = 'bar';
```

If I don't decode the var1 first and I just encode the whole array I get a result like so

`{"var1":"{\"test\":\"test\"}","var2":"foo","var3":"bar"}`

Notice the slashes in the json object.

Comment: Why don't you `base64_encode(json_encode($dataArray))` then to turn it back into array `json_decode(base64_decode($base64string))`

Comment: `I feel like this is a waste of resources though` did you test it to find out if it a resource problem?

Comment: **I feel like there has to be a better way.**
You may be "gold plating", here! Ensuring a dependable format for your data is of more importance than resource usage, IMO.

Comment: The issue is if I encode the array it double encodes the json object (since the json object is already encoded it encodes it again) so the json object is pretty much unuseable then.

Comment: @bassxzero  I tested speeds but I have nothing to compare it against so I don't know if there is a better way or not. It's not like this little chunk of code is all that intensive but I have millions and millions of users hitting it so even if I can save a fraction of speed it would go a long way.

Comment: @Cameron Hurd dependable format is for sure important but I feel like there's some what to keep the json encoded and encode the whole array without it re encoding the json object. I just feel like decoding something just to encode it again can't be the best way to do it.

Comment: @Dave https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: @Dave – is it worth adding context about why there's a json-encoded value on your array? Please share an example of your data structure! Maybe someone will be able to help you create an efficient function to pass to array_walk that checks for json serialization and skips, if it's already there. (though, I can't speak to the efficiency of *that* approach. I imagine it's quite a tradeoff.)

Comment: _"re-json_encodes the json and adds slashes to it"_ So? This isn't a problem. When you `json_decode()` the outer array, you'll get back the JSON-encoded inner array, which you can then `json_decode()` separately if you need to.

Comment: @Alex Howansky If I json_decode the outer array I would then have access to the json object you're right but I would then have to strip the slashes off of the value before I json_decode it since the encoding of json that is already in json format adds slashes to all the quotes.

Comment: _"I would then have to strip the slashes off"_ Nope -- `json_encode()` adds them, `json_decode()` removes them. See [here](https://eval.in/890350).

Comment: @bassxzero I understand it's something small and wont make a huge difference it's more so about finding better ways to do things overall. I really feel decoding json just to encode it again right after can't be the best way to do it. Maybe it is, but to me it just seems like there has to be a better way.

Comment: @Alex Howansky that's exactly why I posted this question. I had no idea that json_decode stripped slashes, I don't know  that I ever tried it actually. So even with the slashes added when I run json_decode I still get the results I'm looking for without ever having to json_decode the inner json object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, you got it -- any output that `json_encode()` generates can be correctly reversed simply by calling `json_decode()` -- there is never a need to manually manipulate the encoded string, PHP takes care of all the escaping for you.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` returns a string containing the json representation of a value. 
In the example, a php string is passed as one element of the array `'{"test":"test"}'`, thus `json_encode()` is encoding it appropriately into json format, with escaped quotes `"{\"test\":\"test\"}"`.

If decoding nested json is a very resource heavy task, a workaround is to use a placeholder instead of the value, `{"var1":"PLACEHOLDER","var2":"foo","var3":"bar"}`, and then using `str_replace()` to replace it.

However, simply decoding it as you described is probably a cleaner solution, if its not resource heavy.

Comment: It is not a good idea to call `str_replace()` on a json_encoded string -- this may lead to broken json data.